# Recursive query error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, sql-view

On SQL Server 2008+, I am trying to create a query which will be the code of a view (thus, only one statement allowed... right?), that returns one column with all the possible dates (actually `datetime` but with empty time content) between the minimum value and the maximum value of column `insdate` of table `dt`.

I tried this:

```
;WITH daterange(mindate, maxdate) AS
(
    SELECT
        MIN(insdate) AS mindate,
        MAX(insdate) AS maxdate 
    FROM dt
)
WITH t(specific_day) AS 
(
    SELECT mindate     -- Seed Row
    UNION ALL
    SELECT specific_day + 1 -- Recursion
    FROM t
    WHERE specific_day + 1 <= maxdate
)
SELECT * 
FROM t
OPTION (maxrecursion 5000)
```

but it fails with the all too common error Msg 319. The interesting thing is that each of the 'with' clauses work as intended when not combined. Am I missing some rule like "recursive cte must be first"? How can I achieve my initial purpose?

Comment: "but it fails with the all too common error Msg 319" Are we supposed to guess the error text, or remember it by heart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use more than one CTE, you don't need to specify `WITH` multiple times, just chain them with a comma:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (...),
CTE2 AS (...),
CTE3 AS ....
```

But I'd reccommend a different approach entirely. If you have a calendar table, then this becomes a pretty basic query:

```
WITH DateRange (MinDate, MaxDate) AS
(
    SELECT MIN(InsDate), MAX(InsDate) 
    FROM dt
)
SELECT  c.Date 
FROM    dbo.Calendar AS c
        INNER JOIN DateRange AS dr
            ON dr.MinDate <= c.Date
            AND dr.MaxDate >= c.Date;
```

If you don't have a calendar table, then you can generate a list of dates on the fly. Much more reading about this is here:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)

Part 3 is specifically relevant as it deals with dates.

The easiest way though, is to just generate a list of sequential numbers the size of your range, and add each number to your start date, e.g.

```
WITH DateRange (MinDate, MaxDate) AS
(
    SELECT MIN(InsDate), MAX(InsDate)
    --FROM dt
    FROM (VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, '20170101')), (CONVERT(DATE, '20180101'))) dt (InsDate)
), Numbers AS
(   SELECT  Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY n1.n) - 1
    FROM    (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS n1 (n) 
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS n2 (n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS n3 (n)
)
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, dr.MinDate)
FROM    DateRange AS dr
        INNER JOIN Numbers AS n
            ON n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, dr.MinDate, dr.MaxDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to:

```
    ;with daterange(mindate,maxdate) as 
    (
        select min(insdate) as mindate,max(insdate) as maxdate from dt
    )
    , t(specific_day) AS (
      SELECT mindate FROM daterange    -- Seed Row
      UNION ALL
      SELECT specific_day+1 -- Recursion
      FROM t
      where specific_day+1<=(select maxdate from daterange)
    )
    select * from t
    option (maxrecursion 5000)
```

Comment: Wow, fast! I get error invalid column name mindate and maxdate in this case.

Comment: I've made a small change, try again

Comment: it works! I'll accept this after the 9 mins have passed^^ so I was missing the comma?

Comment: A recursive CTE doesn't have be the first in the execution. you can't start a new CTE with another "WITH" additional CTE's should be differentiated by comma